# Print Epoch Time in Different Languages

Tags: unix, datetime, time, epoch

As you may know, tonight, at exactly 23:31:30 UTC, Epoch Time will reach 1234567890! Hurray!

One way of watching epoch time is by using Perl:

```
perl -le 'while(true){print time();sleep 1;}'
```

Can you do the same in another programming language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this [site](http://www.epochconverter.com/) is in my favorites and has many answers for it

Answer (score 2):

python one-line:

```
python -c "while True: import time;print time.time();time.sleep(1)"
```

Answer (score 1):

shell script:

```
while :; do printf "%s\r" $(date +%s); sleep 1; done
```

python:

```
import time
import sys

while True:
    sys.stdout.write("%d\r" % time.time())
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

php  one-liner

```
php -r 'while(true) { echo time(), "\n"; sleep(1);}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Zsh - Advanced Unix Shell:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime && while true; do print $EPOCHSECONDS ; sleep 1; done
```

Answer (score 0):

java:

```
System.out.println((new java.util.Date(0)).toString());
```

That's the epoch :) ... the *current* time would be:

```
System.out.println((new java.util.Date()).toString());
```

For getting the amount of milliseconds passed since the epoch, do:

```
System.out.println("" + (new java.util.Date()).getTime());
```

Comment: This prints the Epoch (a specific moment in time), not "Epoch Time" which is the time elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00. 

The output of your program does not match mine.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the same code in c#:

```
    DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((int)(DateTime.UtcNow - epoch).TotalSeconds);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

And like tehvan said, it's the *current* time, not "Epoch" time

Comment: Epoch Time is the time elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

Java

```
import java.util.Date;

public class EpochTime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More perl:

```
perl -MAnyEvent -MDateTime -E 'my $cv = AE::cv; my $w = AE::timer 0, 1, sub { say DateTime->now->epoch }; $cv->wait'
```